# Feature image won't display

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently I'm making new theme and had the idea of adding featured image in the admin side of wordpress, unfortunately its not working this is what I have tried

I have added this code in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```

I also tried to change it

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); // Add it for posts
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) ); // Add it for pages
```

After I refresh and log in to my admin panel and tried to create new post or page featured image is not displaying.

I also tried deactivating my custom theme and activating Twenty Fifteen the featured images shows but if I activate my custom theme again the featured image is gone again.

I also have tried to look at SCREEN OPTIONS but I don't have any available checkbox related to featured image, please help me.

Can someone help or guide me what to do this because I'm new to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to tie your `add_theme_support` call to WP action, for example `after_setup_theme`.

Here's sample code for this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'themename_post_thumbs_en', 11);
function themename_post_thumbs_en() {
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page'));
}
```